# Does the colour of your weapon affect your camo index?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

Unlocking the option to customise your weapons allows you to change the colour of the weapon - Does this affect the likelihood of being spotted?

For instance, if I've got a bright pink gun, am I more likely to be spotted than if it was a brown camo pattern?

Comment: Seems very unlikely that it would affect your camo index. Can't verify this though.

Comment: If it is true, it would be kind of a dick move, since rubber bullet weapons like the RIOT SMG and the nonlethal version of the UN-ARC are painted bright blue by default.

Comment: @LucasLeblanc I hope that it's not - Just with all the attention to detail put into this game, I wouldn't be surprised if it is!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've colored all my non-lethal guns in the same bright blue color that their parts are highlighted with. I haven't noticed a single change to the detection enemy AI.

However, these guns might make you stick out in FOB to other players.